# Error while compiling a local Substrate node: bitswap.v1.2.0.proto + librocksdb-sys

Tags: substrate-node-template

I'm trying to compile a local Substrate node and receive the following :

```
caladay@LAPTOP-GTIDPPCA:~/substrate-node-template$ cargo build --release
   Compiling librocksdb-sys v0.8.0+7.4.4
   Compiling sc-network-bitswap v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.32#5ea6d953)
error: failed to run custom build command for `sc-network-bitswap v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.32#5ea6d953)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/caladay/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/sc-network-bitswap-358d1cd360199f79/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  Running: "/usr/bin/protoc" "--include_imports" "--include_source_info" "-o" "/tmp/prost-build2QKUaS/prost-descriptor-set" "-I" "src/schema" "bitswap.v1.2.0.proto"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { kind: Other, error: "protoc failed: bitswap.v1.2.0.proto: No such file or directory\n" }', /home/caladay/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/5ea6d95/client/network/bitswap/build.rs:4:58
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: snappy/snappy.cc:1033:36: error: invalid output constraint '=@ccz' in asm
warning:       : [tag_type] "+r"(tag_type), "=@ccz"(is_literal));
warning:                                    ^
warning: 1 error generated.

error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v0.8.0+7.4.4`
```

I tried to install clang (as metioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66583720/some-error-failed-to-run-custom-build-command-for-librocksdb-sys-v6-11-4)). Do you have any suggestions ?

As suggested by @AurevoirXavier I installed g++. It seems that it was already installed but the error message evolved:

```
caladay@LAPTOP-GTIDPPCA:~/substrate-node-template$ cargo build --release
   Compiling sc-network-bitswap v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.32#5ea6d953)
   Compiling kvdb-rocksdb v0.16.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `sc-network-bitswap v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.32#5ea6d953)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/caladay/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/sc-network-bitswap-358d1cd360199f79/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  Running: "/usr/bin/protoc" "--include_imports" "--include_source_info" "-o" "/tmp/prost-build3AYt6r/prost-descriptor-set" "-I" "src/schema" "bitswap.v1.2.0.proto"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { kind: Other, error: "protoc failed: bitswap.v1.2.0.proto: No such file or directory\n" }', /home/caladay/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/5ea6d95/client/network/bitswap/build.rs:4:58
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Rust toolchain:

```
caladay@LAPTOP-GTIDPPCA:~/substrate-node-template$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/caladay/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.65.0 (897e37553 2022-11-02)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Ubuntu and wls and reinstalled it from the Microsoft store and somehow it now works. So if anyone is experiencing a similar problem I would suggest doing the same.
Thank you @AurevoirXavier and @DanShields for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the `g++`? I think `librocksdb-sys` requires `g++`.

Comment: It seems to me that it was already installed. I still launched sudo apt install g++ (0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded). But somehow the error message evolved (see the update above)

Comment: How about `apt install protobuf-compiler`?

Comment: it is already installed.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't in your $PATH?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken the protoc file is stored under /usr/bin which is included in my PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the logs there you need protoc. see the deps needed here https://docs.substrate.io/install/linux/

If a Debian based distribution, you likely need

```sh
sudo apt install --assume-yes git clang curl libssl-dev llvm libudev-dev make protobuf-compiler
```

protoc is part of protobuf-compiler

Comment: As I'm on windows, I followed this setup: https://docs.substrate.io/install/windows/ (i.e. it seems similar to the linux one except I had to install wls). It is installed: protoc --version -->
libprotoc 3.0.0

Comment: And its working? Perhaps a PR is needed upstream on the windows install instruction?

Comment: Not sure I understand you. I installed protoc on windows, with the same result.

Comment: If there was something that resolved this that you could identify as missing in the installation instructions, those should be updated.

Comment: Seems though that its unclear what the issue was from your answer. So we will see if others hit the same snag and help us find the issue